# I want a report whether data is increased or decreased between two financial years

Tags: mysql, sql

2014-15 is a financial year in which i have taken a survey of houses in what sqft they are...
In 2015-16 am taking the same survey and there are no much changes but few houses have increased in their sqft and have built a floor which makes a difference in sqft...

NOW how can i compare both the financial years according to the survey data and just give the reports of the data which is only changed

2014-15 survey result
H.NO.1-->1000sqft
H.NO.2-->900sqft
2015-16 survey result
H.NO.1-->1100sqft
H.NO.2-->900sqft
 Here in this i have to display H.NO.1 in report as it is changed.Unchanged will not be showed in the report.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey, we need a little example to help you !

Answer (score 1):

select * from survey p , survey c where c.financialyear  = '2014-15' and p.financialyear = '2015-16'
and c.houseNo = p.houseNo and c.sqfeet != p.sqfeet;